# how to attach a Audio file to the MFMessage Composer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller

I an new to Iphone developing now i have a problem with `MFMessageComposer` how to attach a audio file with message like MMS .I knew how to attach attachments to MFMailComposeViewController but i want for MFMessageComposeViewController please help...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

No ,you just can't share images,video or audio file s from your app in iOS
 This is perhaps because of the infringement issues

Answer (score 0):

MFMessageComposeViewController has a couple of addAttachment... methods that should be useful for what you are trying to do.

[image: MFMessageAddAttachments]